# Previously Compiled P/L SQL Now Freezes in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am at a complete loss as to where my issue is. Earlier on I wrote a procedure that compiled fine, however now I notice that if I take the exact code (even copy/paste from the procedure itself), and try to run it again, SQL Developer essentially freezes and it never compiles.

The SQL itself is certainly not the cleanest, and I am aware that I've made it a little more complex than a better programmer would, however if it compiled earlier it should compile again, no? Below is the P/L SQL in case that may help...

```
create or replace  PROCEDURE insert_comments AS

v_blob BLOB; v_record number;

BEGIN


SELECT blob_content INTO v_blob from xlsx_files;

for x in 
    (select id into v_record from  
        (SELECT to_number(id) id, name FROM 
            (WITH xlsx AS 
                (SELECT
                    ROW_NR,
                    COL_NR,
                    CASE CELL_TYPE
                        WHEN 'S'
                            THEN STRING_VAL
                        WHEN 'N'
                            THEN TO_CLOB(NUMBER_VAL)
                        WHEN 'D'
                            THEN TO_CLOB(TO_CHAR(DATE_VAL, 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
                        ELSE 
                            TO_CLOB(FORMULA)
                    END CELL_VAL
                FROM
                    (SELECT * FROM
                        TABLE(as_read_xlsx_clob.read(v_blob )) 
                        --as_read_xlsx_clob is a function from the As_read_XLSX_CLOB package
                    )   
                ) 
            /*The below statement works as a roundabout way of pivoting 
            the table. Since the data in the file may contain CLOBs, you 
            can't use the PIVOT function since CLOBs do not support 
            aggregation. I have commented out the original SQL that used 
            PIVOT*/ 
            SELECT id_table.id, name_table.name FROM 
                (SELECT row_nr, cell_val id FROM
                    (SELECT * FROM xlsx WHERE row_nr > 1) id_table 
                     where id_table.col_nr=1
                ) id_table
                inner join 
                (SELECT row_nr, cell_val name FROM
                    (SELECT  *
                    FROM xlsx 
                        --PIVOT (MAX(TO_CHAR(CELL_VAL)) 
                        FOR COL_NR IN (1 AS ROW_WID,2 AS NAME)
                        ) ad 
                        WHERE row_nr >1
                    ) name_table  
                    where name_table.col_nr = 2
                ) name_table 
            ON id_table.row_nr = name_table.row_nr
            )
        )
    )
loop
   v_record := x.id;
   INSERT INTO comment_test(id, name) 
       (SELECT to_number(id) id, name 
        FROM 
            (WITH xlsx AS
                (SELECT
                    ROW_NR,
                    COL_NR,
                    CASE CELL_TYPE
                        WHEN 'S'
                            THEN STRING_VAL
                        WHEN 'N'
                            THEN TO_CLOB(NUMBER_VAL)
                        WHEN 'D'
                            THEN TO_CLOB(TO_CHAR(DATE_VAL, 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
                        ELSE TO_CLOB(FORMULA)
                    END CELL_VAL
                FROM
                (SELECT * FROM
                    TABLE(as_read_xlsx_clob.read(v_blob )) 
                    --as_read_xlsx_clob is a function from the As_read_XLSX_CLOB package
                )   
            ) 
            /*The below statement works as a roundabout way of
            pivoting the table. Since the data in the file may
            contain CLOBs,  you can't use the PIVOT function since
            CLOBs do not support aggregation. I have commented out
            the original SQL that used PIVOT*/ 
            SELECT id_table.id, name_table.name FROM 
                (SELECT row_nr, cell_val id FROM
                    (SELECT * FROM xlsx WHERE row_nr > 1) id_table 
                where id_table.col_nr=1
                ) id_table
                inner join 
                (SELECT row_nr, cell_val name FROM
                    (SELECT  *
                     xlsx 
                        --PIVOT (MAX(TO_CHAR(CELL_VAL)) 
                        FOR COL_NR IN (1 AS ROW_WID,2 AS NAME)
                        ) ad
                     WHERE row_nr >1
                    ) name_table 
                 where name_table.col_nr = 2
                ) name_table 
                ON id_table.row_nr = name_table.row_nr) 
            where to_number(id) = v_record 
       );
   end loop;

delete from xlsx_files; 
END;
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted the exact code which you are trying to compile becuase i can see syntax error in your posted code above.

Comment: Yeah, copied directly from the procedure. It seems to compile fine in a different connection (so long as the referenced tables exist). Mind pointin gout the syntax error?

Comment: It seems very system specific issue. You need to check if the system you are running have all the DB objects and you have necessary grants to execute the proc.

Comment: For reference in general -- For one reason or another when copying and formatting the PL SQL above, syntax errors are being created. For sake of the thread, the PL SQL stored in my existing procedure does not have errors and can be ran on any other database except this one in question.

Comment: I am going to go ahead and update SQL Developer since I realized it is fairly out of date anyways. The database has all objects and I do have necessary grants (I was able to run this statement earlier this morning). Will post back if it ended up just being a session management issue fixed by upgrading.

Comment: Is the procedure currently in use in another session which is blocking recompilation? (Your partially commented-out `pivot` subquery as posted is messed up, but this is probably as you say a copy/paste/formatting issue. Is it possible that there is some stray control characters or something that could be confusing both SO and SQL Developer?)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I think there being another session is actually the case. I just tried to run the statement with a different name (INSERT_COMMENTS2) and the procedure compiled. I'm currently trying to figure out how to identify which session this is as this is a new topic for me, but hoping that if I can kill that session it will resolve my issues. Any suggestions are certainly appreciated :)

Comment: This kind of thing? http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/02/locks-and-killing-sessions-in-oracle-sql-developer/

Comment: Or just look at the `BLOCKING_%` columns in [`v$session`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-28E2DC75-E157-4C0A-94AB-117C205789B9.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per William Robertson's comments, the issue was there was another session which was using the procedure. This session was killed and I was able to recompile.